# Writing a delete algorithm in an ordered linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to write a delete algorithm for an ordered linked list. Search and traverse I think I have down but delete is giving me fits. It crashes every time. Can someone help me fix this?

I have a private pointer to a `ListNode` structure called `head` in my `TestLL` class. The `ListNode` structure contains `int Key`, `double dataValue`, and `ListNode *next`. The function returns `true` if the node to delete was found and deleted or `false` if it was not found.

My code:

```
bool TestLL::Delete(int Key)
{
    ListNode *back = NULL, *temp = head;
    //Search for the node to delete
    while ((temp != NULL) && (key != temp -> key))
        //advance the pointers
        back = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    //Check for node to delete not being found
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Check for deleting the head of the list
    else if (back == NULL) // I'm very unsure of my else if and else
    {
        delete temp;
    }
    else // Remove node other than at the head
    {
        delete temp;
    }

    //deallocate memory used by the removed node
    free(temp);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: First `delete` then `free`? That doesn't make sense. Why do you think that you need to release memory twice using different methods?

Comment: You have an odd # of brackets...one is missing.  Looks like you need an opening bracket right after the while(......) statement.

Comment: You showed code that has syntctical errors. For example there is no open brace in this code snippet while((temp != NULL) && (key != temp -> key))
//advance the pointers
back = temp;
temp = temp->next;
}

Comment: @trying In no way is the person trying to select a particular data structure. There's absolutely no reason to add a data structure tag to every question about linked lists. Also, please don't make multiple edits to questions just to add tags. Fix everything in one edit.

Answer (score 0):

The function could look for example the following way (without testing)

```
bool TestLL::Delete( int key )
{
    ListNode *prev = nullptr, *current = head;

    while ( current && !( current->key == key ) )
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if ( !current ) return false;

    if ( prev ) prev->next = current->next;
    else head = head->next;

    delete current;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using both `delete` and `free` on the same pointer is definitely a problem.

- If you used `new` to allocate the memory, use `delete`
- If you used `malloc`, remind yourself that you're using C++ and replace it with `new`.

If `back == NULL`, this means:

- `head` is `NULL` (in which case, just `return false`) or
- The first element is the one we want to delete (in which case you need to remove the element at `head` from the list, i.e. `head = head->next; delete temp;`)

If `temp == NULL`, this means the element was not found - you correctly just `return false` here.

If `temp != NULL`, you need to remove `temp`: `back->next = temp->next; delete temp;`.

But just using a pointer to a pointer seems simpler:

```
bool TestLL::deleteKey(int key)
{
    ListNode **current = &head;
    while (*current != NULL)
    {
        if ((*current)->key == key)
        {
            ListNode *temp = *current;
            *current = (*current)->next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
        }
        current = &(*current)->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Um... `current` is a *reference* to the `head` member variable. Each time you execute `current = current->next` you're replacing the address in `head` with the address in `head->next`. I'm fairly sure this is *not* what you want. Ex: if the list did not contain the value being sought, you just leaked the entire linked list, as `head` will be `nullptr` on exit. Also, `delete` isn't a valid name for a member function; it is a reserved keyword in the language.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh, right, I can't believe I missed that. Changed my function to use a *pointer* to a pointer instead and renamed my function.